# Как из массива объектов выбрать определенные значения в этих объектах и записать их в новый массив?

Tags: php, redbeanphp

у меня есть выборка из записей БД в виде массива объектов RedBean, мне необходимо из них получить ассоциативный массив вида ["id" => значение из объекта массива, "nik" = > значение из объекта массива], если я делаю код ниже для одного значения (nik), то все работает, как надо, а когда для двух, то выдает только массив с одним элементом, никак не соображу, что я делаю не так...

public static function getContactsID($id) {

```
$findId = R::getAll('SELECT `first_id` FROM `contacts` WHERE `second_id` = ?', [$id]);

array_walk_recursive($findId, function($item) use (&$result) {
    $result[] = $item;
});

$findNikEmail = R::findAll('users', 'id IN (' . R::genSlots($findId) . ')', $result);


foreach ($findNikEmail as $numbers){
    foreach ($numbers as $email) {
           
        if ($numbers['username'] == "") {
            $contacts = ["id" => $numbers['id'], "nik" => $numbers['email']];
        } else {
            $contacts = ["id" => $numbers['id'], "nik" => $numbers['username']];
        } 
    }
    
  }


var_dump($contacts);

$resultContacts = array_unique($contacts);

  return $resultContacts;
```

}

Comment: `$contacts[] = ['id' => ..., 'nik' => $numbers['username'] ?? $numbers['email']]` вместо `if-else`

Comment: `foreach` второй там судя по всему тоже не нужен

Comment: да, Вы правы - второй foreach не нужен, Ваше предложение выше работает, спасибо, но вот почему-то там где нет username вместо email пишет пустую строку...

Comment: вот так заработало так, как надо, спасибо $contacts[] = ['id' => $numbers['id'], 'nik' => ($numbers['username'] == "" ? null : $numbers['username']) ?? $numbers['email']];

Comment: `$numbers['username'] ?: $numbers['email']` хватило бы, наверное.

Comment: да-да, так тоже работает, спасибо